# Pagination data from Find method GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to implement pagination using limits and offsets in my GORM app. Ive been coding in node or java in the past where the major ORMS all had some utilities to retrieve pagination data along side the result set. I dont seem to find anything similar using GORM.

When I query my database using .Limit, .Offset & Find, the RowsAffected return the amount of rows set to be returned via the limit. How am I able to construct a custom struct that holds data like page (I get that from the user), offset (calculating myself), totalElements (need this), totalPages (need this as well).

I browsed the documentation and could not find any answer to my question. Is pagination not implemented in GORM?